# Rounding Python Values to the Nearest Half Number

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm struggling with a few things right now using python dataframes. I have one column with a long list of numbers ranging from 1-5. For example, the column contains the values (3.6, 2.1, 4.7, 3.8, 1.9, etc., etc.). What I want to do is round each number to the nearest HALF number (not the nearest whole number).

What I want to do is create a new column that would return the values (3.5, 2.0, 4.5, 4.0, 2.0, etc.). Conceptually, this is super easy, but I'm having trouble doing this within the dataframe.

My initial idea was to use the int function to get a value rounded to the nearest whole number. Then I would subtract my initial value from that. Then, based on the returned value, I would determine how to round each value. So far, however, I've been unsuccessful.

I keep running into the following error for example: "cannot convert the series to "

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbaxI.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `round` and a little arithmetic to get your desired result:

`round(num*2)/2` will round a number to the nearest `0.5`.

Here is how you would apply this to a dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [3.6, 2.1, 4.7, 3.8, 1.9]})
>>> df
   col1
0   3.6
1   2.1
2   4.7
3   3.8
4   1.9
>>> df['col2'] = df.col1.mul(2).round().div(2)
>>> df
   col1  col2
0   3.6   3.5
1   2.1   2.0
2   4.7   4.5
3   3.8   4.0
4   1.9   2.0
```